# Excel vba textbox

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a code in excel vba for copying multiple cell values of Range to textbox. I have written a code to copy each cell value one by one and copy it to textbox. Code is executing fine but instead of copying all cells it shows value of last cell only. It is over writting the text box values. Somehow I am missing the trick to copy next cell value to next line in text box. Can anyone gelp me fix this.
I posting question from mobile so please excuse my indentation.

```
Sub ToText1()

Dim txtShap As Shape
RowL = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row        
Set txtShap = Workbooks("Concat.xlsb").Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("TextBox 6")
For i = 2 To RowL
    'MsgBox i
    txtShap.TextFrame.Characters.Text = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & RowL) .Value & vbNewLine
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to concatenate the two instead of constantly overwriting plus you need to include the `i` instead of the last row `txtShap.TextFrame.Characters.Text = txtShap.TextFrame.Characters.Text & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C"& i).Value & vbNewLine`

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked.✌✌✌ had to do correction in Range("C" & RowL) to ("C" & i) , a mistake commited while writting code here.

Comment: Changed it for you

Comment: Btw, please send these as an answer, and not a comment.